# Triggers PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have an exercise on triggers in PostgreSQL.

I have 2 tables : "commande" and "ligne_commande".

- In the table "ligne_commande" there are 4 columns :
  *codecommande - codeligne - quantité - codepdt*
- In the table "commande" there are 6 columns :
  *codecommande - datecommande - montantht - codeclient - codevendeur - coderemise*

I need to create a trigger that for each modification / insertion / deletion in ligne_commande calculate the amount of an order (*montantht* in the table commande).

I already have the following function that calculate the amount of an order (made in a previous exercise) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verifmontantht(VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS boolean AS '
DECLARE
verifmontantht commande.montantht%TYPE;

BEGIN

    SELECT INTO verifmontantht (SUM(produit.prixpdt * ligne_commande.quantite) * (100 - COALESCE(commande.coderemise,0))/100)::numeric(7,2) AS "Montant vérifié"
FROM commande JOIN ligne_commande ON commande.codecommande = ligne_commande.codecommande
                JOIN produit ON ligne_commande.codepdt = produit.codepdt
WHERE commande.codecommande = $1
GROUP BY commande.codecommande, commande.datecommande, commande.montantht, commande.coderemise
ORDER BY commande.codecommande;

END;
'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I can't find a way to make a trigger that can use this function or should I create another function because this one doesn't have RETURN TRIGGER AS $..$

Do you have any advice that could help me ? Because I'm really stuck on that one..

Thank you very much for you help :)

Comment: The trigger function will have to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on the other table. The task is unclear, because it doesn't specify what the primary keys are, and whether it should be an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

Comment: Ok I understand for the INSERT or UPDATE part. But what do you mean with the unclear task ? (Sorry my english is not that good..) Maybe my explanation wasn't good enough ?..

I'm also sorry I edited my function in the first message because it had some unnecessary parts. 

Thanks for your answer !